# How to efficiently iterate a Multimap?

Tags: java

I have the following multimap:

```
Multimap<String,Multimap<String,Integer>>  map =  ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

I need to iterate it, but I am stuck.

How should I iterate it?

Comment: Iterate how? What do you try to achieve? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using [google guava multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and the [create method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#create--) of the class [`ArrayListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) to create it.

You can iterate through your multimap and your inner multimap like this:

```
package com.test.java;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Multimap<String, Multimap<String,Integer>>  map =  ArrayListMultimap.create();

        Multimap<String,Integer> m = ArrayListMultimap.create();

        //put some values
        m.put("value1", 1);
        m.put("value2", 2);
        m.put("value3", 3);

        map.put("one", m);

        for (Object value1 : map.values()) { 
            for (Object value2 : ((Multimap<String,Integer>)value1).values()) { 
                System.out.println((Integer)value2);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
2
1
3
```

**Note:**

If you want to have a deterministic iteration order, use [LinkedListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html):

**Example:**

```
LinkedListMultimap<String, LinkedListMultimap<String,Integer>>  map =  LinkedListMultimap.create();

LinkedListMultimap<String,Integer> m = LinkedListMultimap.create();

//put some values
m.put("value1", 1);
m.put("value2", 2);
m.put("value3", 3);

map.put("one", m);

for (Object value1 : map.values()) { 
    for (Object value2 : ((LinkedListMultimap<String,Integer>)value1).values()) { 
        System.out.println((Integer)value2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Multimap<String>> map = multimap.asMap();
System.out.println("Multimap as a map");

for (Map.Entry<String,  Multimap<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Multimap<String> value =  multimap.get("lower");
    System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
}
```

please try it out.

Comment: I have a multimap and its value as one more multimap will above sol work?

Answer (score 0):

my example

```java
        ListMultimap<Long, Long> items = elasticResult.getResult();

        for (Long key : items.keySet()) {
            items.get(key).forEach(value -> {
                  // ... use key and value
            });
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider to add an explanation to your solution (e.g. why is it better than the other answers, why does it solve the problem), as it's currently barely intelligible for unexperienced users.